# How to properly name REST methods for finding entity by Id and by name?

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, api-design

By convention, REST methods should be nouns and should answer the question "What?" rather than "How?".

So, given that I only need to make find-by-id method, I can easily come up with the RESTful path `/foo/{id}`, where the part in brackets is substituted by some number.

Now, I also need to add find-by-name method, but I cannot use `/foo/{name}` as it's already taken.

I cannot also add 'name'-section to the path (i.e. the path would look like `/foo/name/{name}`), because it would mean "This method returns Foo's name".

What can be an appropriate way to compose this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the right way to it is smt like

```
 /foo?name=bar
```

By querying in this way you will be able return several `foo` with same name. If for one `name` there are always no more than one `foo` perhaps name should be your id.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having both `/foo/{name}` and `/foo/{id}`. URI semantics are transparent to REST. Trying to embed behavior in URI doesn't make much sense in REST, where that behavior is supposed to come from the media type, the URI merely gives its location. `/foo/name/{name}` doesn't mean "this method returns Foo's name". It means whatever the source of the hyperlink giving you that URI template says it does.

The appropriate way to do what you want is having `/foo` returning an hyperlink title "Find Foo by name" or something like that. This hyperlink can be an URI template that when expanded with the `name` will retrieve a search result with the desired Foo, if it exists.

That uritemplate can be `/foo/{name}`, `/foo?name={name}`, `/search?type=foo&name={name}`, or even something totally unrelated like `/my/api/is/a/mess?name={name}`. It doesn't really matter, because all the client will do is retrieve that uritemplate, expand it, and retrieve the resource.

Obviously, you're encouraged to think carefully about your paths and make them meaningful and intuitive to client developers, but adopting one or other style doesn't make your API more or less RESTful and you can't say it's more or less appropriate. If you're thinking too much about that, it's probably because you're API [is not hypertext driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven), and not RESTful at all. Other implementation details, like your framework, will probably have more of a voice on the degree of appropriateness of one or the other than the REST constraints. For instance, some frameworks may have trouble with routing to both `foo/{name}` and `/foo/{id}`, but as I said above, that's not a problem at all for REST.